# How to calculate point 'along' unit circle radian

Tags: trigonometry, geometry

See this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqKjE.png

Given P1 and circle radius, is there a method to calculate P2?

I am able to get the angle at P1, as well as the relevant distances and points defined by the triangle that would form inside the circle (and whose hypotenuse is along P1 & P1.)

I presume the solution has something to do with the angle at P1...

Comment: Trig or pythagorus could solve that. What are you actually asking for, the math?

Comment: Yes, looking for the math. Would it be a process of adding the distance from the origin to the point? If, per se, origin X is 0, and distance to P2 is 5, P2 X is .... No, that clearly wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the distance `r` between `P1` and `P2` and the orientation angle `t`

```
P2.X = P1.X + r*COS(t)
P2.Y = P2.Y - r*SIN(t)
```

Note the angle `t` is in radians, or `t=π/180*degrees`.

Comment: The clear and concise answer I was hoping to receive. Thanks!